# redirection doesn't change view in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm new with angular and I don't know how redirect correctly. I was doing this simple page in stackblitz to test it, but my redirection doesn't works well, because the info of html doesn't change. What is my fault?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2bxumx?file=app%2Fpage1%2Fpage1.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing router outlet tag on your html... and also need to add a default route:

Notice if you add following line in app.compontne.ts your page1 will load when clicked:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Asso, remember to set a default route so that when your app loads the router will have something to show:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [  
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'hello', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent },
  ...
];
```

I recommend you at least glance at the docs on [navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Comment: Thank you, but now I have a new question. With your solution the redirection becomes directly, not just on click over the button. I will go to start this tutorial from the begin, but can you tell me how can I do the redirection just one click over the button.

Comment: Are you sure? I just went to your stakblitz link and it showed the message on the top of the page only after I clicked on the button....

Comment: Yes it's correct. I do not know how I looked at it, but it works fine, thank you!